# confirm JS sweetalert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Здравствуйте.

На сайте везде в js-скриптах на некоторых функциях стоит проверка

```
function name(){
      if (!confirm("Удалить?"))
        {
         return;
        }
......выполнение....
}
```

Начал использовать sweetalert для bootstrap
Но понял, что во всех файлах убирать проверку confirm - будет очень долго . 
Решил попробовать схитрить  - просто переопределить функцию

```
function confirm(text){

     swal({
        title: text,
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn',
        cancelButtonText: 'Нет',
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
        confirmButtonText: "Да",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function (isConfirm) {

          if (isConfirm) {
              //тут подтверждение
          } else {
              //тут отказ
          }

    });


}
```

Подскажите, как заставить эту функцию отдавать true или false , чтобы везде проверка срабатывала правильно ?

Comment: никак *(10 символов нужно...)*

Comment: объясните пожалуйста, не понял

Comment: Не, ну серьезно, не делайте так а то кто-то в будущем будет очень жалеть (возможно Вы)

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian Вы меняете вызов блокирующей функции на вызов неблокирующей функции. Подменой `confirm` это сделать не выйдет.